# PXE Server Build

Tags: linux, windows, vmware, pxe

So what if I already have a DHCP server and a DNS Server, How do I build it with out those components? Would DHCP and DNS Conflict with what I already have?

Comment: I cannot quite tell from your question what you are asking for. Are you looking for [proxyDHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)? dnsmasq supports that mode of operation.

Comment: You want to build a PXE server which relies upon your existing DHCP and DNS servers? Is that right? If so, you should [edit] your question and state it (a little more) explicitly. If not, then you'll still need to [edit] and state clearly what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You would need to:

- set up a TFTP server for providing the initial netboot files (for most cases). For Linux, these files would usually be the PXE bootloader file (often [PXELINUX](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX) or [iPXE](https://ipxe.org)), its configuration file, a kernel file, and an initramfs file.
- set up a HTTP or SMB server for providing the rest of the files required by the network-booting OS (details will depend on which OS you're going to PXE boot)
- configure your existing DHCP server to provide the necessary PXE boot options when it receives a request that includes DHCP option #60 (option `vendor-class-identifier` in ISC DHCPD) with the first 9 characters of the option value set to `PXEClient`.

  - the necessary options will in most case be the IP address of the TFTP server, expressed as either classic bootp-style `siaddr` (`next-server` in ISC DHCPD) or as DHCP option #66 (`option tftp-server-name` in ISC DHCPD), and the TFTP pathname of the file that should be loaded by the PXE firmware, again expressible in classic bootp-style (`filename` in ISC DHCPD) or as DHCP option #67 (`option bootfile-name` in ISC DHCPD).
  - you might want to provide one set of PXE boot options if the request's DHCP option #93 has value 0 (indicating an x86 system with a classic BIOS-style boot) and another set if it has value 7 (a 64-bit x86 system with a UEFI-style boot). See [RFC 4578 errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/rfc4578) and [IANA list of DHCPv6 processor architecture types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dhcpv6-parameters/dhcpv6-parameters.xhtml#processor-architecture): the same values are used for IPv4 PXE boot here.
  - for UEFI-style clients, be aware that UEFI firmware may need the size of the boot file reported in DHCP option #13, so the firmware can allocate a correct amount of memory for the boot file it will be loading over the network. If you don't specify this correctly, the firmware phase of the UEFI PXE boot may fail in a very uninformative way.
  - if you choose to use [iPXE](https://ipxe.org) as your PXE bootloader, you'll also want to detect the value "iPXE" in DHCP option #77 (option `user-class` in ISC DHCPD) and provide an iPXE configuration URL instead of a bootloader filename, as this indicates iPXE has successfully initialized and is requesting a configuration file. iPXE can use HTTP instead of TFTP to achieve a much faster boot.
- a DNS server is not strictly necessary, but it can be convenient.

All these server applications can reside in a single (physical or virtual) server host; they don't have to be separate systems.